# Ruby on Rails CSS support

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, css-selectors

I am working on a personal project using Ruby on Rails v.6.0.2.2. I was coding a CSS Responsive menu this morning I had all sorts of problems. The mobile menu button was not working. It is a HTML/CSS only menu I have used in the past, which works fine [Responsive, Pure CSS Off-Canvas Hamburger Menu](http://Responsive,%20Pure%20CSS%20Off-Canvas%20Hamburger%20Menu).

What I have determined is that Rails/ERB does not seem to support the :target pseudo class. Is there documentation somewhere which specifies the supported CSS classes?

Comment: I would suggest using css framework like bootstrap 4 that work very well with rails and there is a gem that you can use for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, CSS support has nothing to do with Rails. CSS is purely negotiated between your css/html code and the web client. But some Rails components can get between the two, for better of worse.

In this case Turbolinks is probably preventing your `:target` pseudo-class from working. Try adding `data-turbolinks="false"` to your links:

```
<a data-turbolinks="false" href="#p1">Jump to the first paragraph!</a>
```

Or if you are using a link_to helper:

```
link_to "Jump there", your_url(anchor: 'p1'), data: { turbolinks: false }
```